# When I bring a UITextField's input to a variable or UserDefault, the variable/UserDefault ends up as nil

Tags: swift, uitextfield

When I print the .text attribute, `print(inputField.text!)`, it prints `0.0925`, which is what I have entered. But when I bring this to a UserDefault or a variable, 
`defaults.set(Int(inputField.text!), forKey: "taxRate")
print(defaults.value(forKey: "taxRate"))`, it prints `nil`. Is there anyway I can fix this so that the UserDefault prints the correct value?

**I am a massive idiot, and I didn't realize that the number entered should never be an integer, it should be a float/double. Thank you to matt for making me realize this. All I had to do was change `defaults.set(Int(inputField.text!), forKey: "taxRate")` to `defaults.set(Double(inputField.text!), forKey: "taxRate")`.**

Comment: You amazing human. This might work, and I am an idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a massive idiot, and I didn't realize that the number entered should never be an integer, it should be a float/double. Thank you to matt for making me realize this. All I had to do was change

```
defaults.set(Int(inputField.text!), forKey: "taxRate")
```

to

```
defaults.set(Double(inputField.text!), forKey: "taxRate")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the expression

```
Int(inputField.text!)
```

Text is not an Int. Some text might represent an Int but your text, “0.0925”, does not. So `nil` is the right answer and it’s hard to see what else you expect.